# Always use threadpool threads for continuations in async

Tags: f#

Is there a way to instruct F# to always use threadpool threads for continuations in async computation expressions regardless of the synchronization context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you use [Async.SwitchToThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353893.aspx) or another `Switch...` method

like this:

```
async {

   do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool () 
   // ... your other stuff
}
```